# How can I delay these animations without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a one page site and I'm trying to navigate between sections by animating out the current content and then animating in the new content. I've got this to work by using setTimeout() ie. animating out the current content over the course of 500ms and then using setTimeout() to delay the new content animating in 500ms later.

The problem is I find setTimeout() to be unreliable and would far rather have a callback or something that would allow me to animate in the new content **only when** the previous content has been removed.

I realise this can be done by using the callback function in animate() however because of the way all of my code is nested, I don't find it'd be very readable to anyone taking over my work. Ideally I'd like the callback at the top level rather than nested deep within the animation code as it'd be trickier to understand.

FYI I'm using a css3 transition plugin that substitutes the default 'animate()' function for 'transition()' in order to use css transitions - just to avoid any confusion.

This is what I have so far:

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <article id="reception">
    <h1 class="title">
      <img src="/images/reception/title.png" alt="Edge" />
    </h1>
    <img src="/images/reception/1.jpg" alt="" class="tile1" />
    <img src="/images/reception/2.jpg" alt="" class="tile2" />
    <img src="/images/reception/hero.jpg" alt="" class="hero" />
    <img src="/images/reception/content1.jpg" alt="" class="content1" />
    <img src="/images/reception/content2.jpg" alt="" class="content2" />
  </article>
  <article id="floorspace">
    <h1 class="title">
      <img src="/images/floorspace/title.png" alt="Space" />
    </h1>
    <img src="/images/floorspace/1.jpg" alt="" class="tile1" />
    <img src="/images/floorspace/2.jpg" alt="" class="tile2" />
    <img src="/images/floorspace/hero.jpg" alt="" class="hero" />
    <img src="/images/floorspace/content1.jpg" alt="" class="content1" />
    <img src="/images/floorspace/content2.jpg" alt="" class="content2" />
  </article>
</div>
```

Relevant script:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function (e) {
  if ($(':animated').length) {
    return false;
  }

  var section = $.param.fragment();
  var current = $('#content').children(':visible').attr('id');

  // If this is the first load then load in reception content
  if (section === '') {                    
    if (current === 'reception') {
      animateContentIn("reception");                        
    }
    else {                        
      // Animate out existing content
      animateContentOut(current);

      setTimeout(function () {
        animateContentIn("reception");
      }, 500);
    }
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise find the current page content and animate out
    animateContentOut(current);

    setTimeout(function () {
      animateContentIn(section);
    }, 500);
  }               

  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});       

function animateContentIn(activePage) { 
  // Now animate in the new content
  switch (activePage) {
    case "floorspace":
      animateFloorspaceElementsIn();
      break;
    case "reception":
      animateReceptionElementsIn();
      break;
  }
}

function animateContentOut(currentPage) {
  // Now animate in the new content
  switch (currentPage) {
    case "floorspace":                    
      animateFloorspaceElementsOut();
      break;
    case "reception":
      animateReceptionElementsOut();
      break;
  }
}

function animateReceptionElementsIn() {
  $('#reception').show();

  $('#reception .title').transition({
    bottom: 520
  }, 200);

  $('#reception .tile1').transition({
    bottom: 504
  }, 300);

  $('#reception .tile2').transition({
    bottom: 504
  }, 350);

  $('#reception .hero').transition({
    bottom: 40
  }, 500);

  $('#reception .content1').transition({
    bottom: 8
  }, 200);

  $('#reception .content2').transition({
    bottom: 8
  }, 250);
}

function animateReceptionElementsOut() {
  $('#reception .title').transition({
    bottom: -56
  }, 200);

  $('#reception .tile1').transition({
    bottom: -136
  }, 300);

  $('#reception .tile2').transition({
    bottom: -152
  }, 350);

  $('#reception .hero').transition({
    bottom: -464
  }, 500, function () {
    $('#reception').hide();
  });

  $('#reception .content1').transition({
    bottom: -112
  }, 200);

  $('#reception .content2').transition({
    bottom: -104
  }, 250);
}

function animateFloorspaceElementsIn() {
  $('#floorspace').show();

  $('#floorspace .title').transition({
    bottom: 520
  }, 200);

  $('#floorspace .tile1').transition({
    bottom: 504
  }, 300);

  $('#floorspace .tile2').transition({
    bottom: 504
  }, 350);

  $('#floorspace .hero').transition({
    bottom: 40
  }, 500);

  $('#floorspace .content1').transition({
    bottom: 8
  }, 200);

  $('#floorspace .content2').transition({
    bottom: 8
  }, 250);
}

function animateFloorspaceElementsOut() {
  $('#floorspace .title').transition({
    bottom: -56
  }, 200);

  $('#floorspace .tile1').transition({
    bottom: -136
  }, 300);

  $('#floorspace .tile2').transition({
    bottom: -152
  }, 350);

  $('#floorspace .hero').transition({
    bottom: -464
  }, 500, function () {
    $('#floorspace').hide();
  });

  $('#floorspace .content1').transition({
    bottom: -132
  }, 200);

  $('#floorspace .content2').transition({
    bottom: -132
  }, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with an animation library? like [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/)

In the end funcion you set the callback function, it runs when the animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using jquery delay method.
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is a really old question but providing an updated solution if someone will have the same issue.

Using jQuery `animate` method, you can provide a callback to be executed when the animation is completed:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Also simply chaining the animations will work as you expect, and you can use `queue` in order to access and manage the chain you created. Here the official doc which exposes what said above:

https://api.jquery.com/queue/

p.s. at the moment, all the kind of animations you are using, they could be achieved also through pure CSS3 solution.